# Summing values based on number of dynamic form fields

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, forms

I have a form where fields are added or removed dynamically using jquery. (railscast #196/7)

In my usage case I'm looking at a purchase form so I would like to start with a default quantity of one, incrementing by 1 for each `link_to_add_fields` submission and the opposite for a `link_to_remove_fields` submit, so I can get my total price at the end, i.e `quantity x @event.price`.

So if I had 3 `link_to_add_fields` and 2 `link_to_remove_fields`, it would be

```
# 1 is default, 3 is link_to_add_fields, 2 is link_to_remove_fields
(1 + (3 - 2)) x @event.price
# or
2 x @event.price
```

My knowledge of jquery is very little so I would prefer a ruby solution if possible,

thanks!

Application helper

```
def link_to_remove_fields(name, f)  
    f.hidden_field(:_destroy) + link_to_function(name, "remove_fields(this)")  
  end  
end  

def link_to_add_fields(name, f, association)  
  new_object = f.object.class.reflect_on_association(association).klass.new   
  fields = f.fields_for(association, new_object, :child_index => "new_#{association}") do |builder|  
    render(association.to_s.singularize + "_fields", :f => builder)  
  end  
  link_to_function(name, "add_fields(this, '#{association}', '#{escape_javascript(fields)}')")

end
```

application.js

```
function remove_fields(link) {
  $(link).prev("input[type=hidden]").val("1");
  $(link).closest(".fields").hide();
}

function add_fields(link, association, content) {
  var new_id = new Date().getTime();
  var regexp = new RegExp("new_" + association, "g")
  $(link).parent().before(content.replace(regexp, new_id));
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're trying to track quantity, just track quantity.  Don't complicate this by trying to add forms and subtract forms.  In the function remove_fields(link):

```
$(link).prev("input[type=hidden]").val("1");
```

Is being hidden.  This value in .val() should be decremented until 0.  If you are adding quantities, increment the value.  This will be much easier than trying to count all forms which is going to involve more jquery not less.

The psuedocode would look something like this:

```
On click "add quantity", find the line item (either this or a jquery selector)
Within the line item, find the quantity hidden value
Quantity++
```

The remove quantity psuedocode would look the same except:

```
Quantity-- unless 0
```

I'm sorry I can't be more specific on the jquery selectors but it's hard to do without the HTML markup.  See this example (if jsfiddle isn't down):
http://jsfiddle.net/xrfsG/9/

Then in your rails create or save controller action, the params will be much more simple.